# How do I manage storage and display of large amounts of text in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I want to create an app which is a manual / textbook. What would be the best way to manage all the text data and formulas I want to display? Being relatively new to objective C I understand how to hard code the text into the view controller, and I also understand how to use plists. But both these methods don't seem to be very elegant. Any other ideas?

Comment: core data ,if you already heard. if not, learn about it.

Comment: How complex/complicated the structure of your data is? Core Data has quite a bit of a learning curve, and it's not the "Universal One Best  Solution To Everything". If you only want to store key-value pairs, plists are **just fine.**

Comment: I have heard of it, I understand it's kinda like a SQL database. Are there character limits on strings?

Comment: @kaf8963 no, but if you're worried, you can just use binary "blobs".

Comment: (Oh, and while we're at it, this has nothing to do with Xcode at all.)

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm not sure what is complex. I want to have multiple chapters, and then sections in chapters which could be sorted in plists with a couple of properties. Is there a string length limit to plists?

Comment: @kaf8963 no, there isn't.

Comment: If it's a manual or textbook I would advise you to look at iBooks Author by Apple (free from the Mac App Store) which allows you to create interactive books. You can even write your own interactive widgets if the ones supplied don't fit your requirements. There are various 2012 and 2013 WWDC videos available with more detailed information.